# Wordpress Error Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/3024): Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded in

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress

Im getting errors when searching on a my wordpress site.
My database is quite big.
Is there a fix around this error because some search results are not appearing, and now this error is popping up on some results

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/3024): Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded in /home/*****/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2162

Comment: This is all on a shared hosting

Comment: You could increase the max execution time by adding "php_value max_execution_time 300" to your .htaccess-file. You could also change the value in php.ini, if you have access to it. This might work.

But this is just a temporary solution and might have a bad impact on the server or the overall performance. I would try to optimize the queries or the database.

Comment: This is not PHP execution time, but MySQL execution time out. You need to increase MySQL time out limit before running this query

Comment: Same as I have but in Laravel PHP